# pandas: How to get the most frequent item in pandas series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

How can I get the most frequent item in a `pandas` series?

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series("1 5 3 3 3 5 2 1 8 10 2 3 3 3".split()).astype(int)
```

The returned value should be `3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) and extract the first value:

```
res = s.mode().iloc[0]
```

This not necessarily inefficient. As always, test with your data to see what suits.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from scipy.stats.mstats import mode
from collections import Counter

np.random.seed(0)

s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 100000))

def jez_np(s):
    _, idx, counts = np.unique(s, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
    index = idx[np.argmax(counts)]
    val = s[index]
    return val

def pir(s):
    i, r = s.factorize()
    return r[np.bincount(i).argmax()]

%timeit s.mode().iloc[0]                 # 1.82 ms
%timeit pir(s)                           # 2.21 ms
%timeit s.value_counts().index[0]        # 2.52 ms
%timeit mode(s).mode[0]                  # 5.64 ms
%timeit jez_np(s)                        # 8.26 ms
%timeit Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][0]  # 8.27 ms
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and select first value by `index`:

```
val = s.value_counts().index[0]
```

Or [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter

val = Counter(s).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Or numpy solution:

```
_, idx, counts = np.unique(s, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
index = idx[np.argmax(counts)]
val = s[index]
```

Comment: how about series.mode() ?

Comment: @anky_91 - It is slow :(

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.factorize` and `numpy.bincount`

This is very similar to @jezrael's Numpy answer.  The difference is the use of `factorize` and not `numpy.unique`

- `factorize` returns an integer factorization and unique values
- `bincount` counts how many of each unique value
- `argmax` identifies which bin or factor is the most fequent
- Use the position of the bin returned from `argmax` to reference the most frequent value from the array of unique values

---

```
i, r = s.factorize()
r[np.bincount(i).argmax()]

3
```

Comment: Yes.  It should be.   Honestly though I didn't notice your Numpy answer until just a moment ago.  I'm going to delete this and leave a comment on yours.

Comment: I just added timings from this version, seems pretty fast but doesn't seem to beat `pd.Series.mode`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
x=[1,5,3,3,3,5,2,1,8,10,2,3,3,3]
data=pd.DataFrame({"values":x})


print(stats.mode(data["values"]))

output:-ModeResult(mode=array([3], dtype=int64), count=array([6]))
```