# Loop through subsets of rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply

I try to loop trough rows of a DataFrame with a function calculation most frequent element in a series. The function works perfectly when i manually supply a series into it:

```
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
              'b' : [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
              'c' : [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]})

# Create function calculating most frequent element
from collections import Counter

def freq_value(series):
    return Counter(series).most_common()[0][0]

# Test function on one row
freq_value(df.iloc[1])

# Another test
freq_value((df.iloc[1, 0], df.iloc[1, 1], df.iloc[1, 2]))
```

With both tests I get the desired result. However, when i try to apply this function in a loop through DataFrame rows and save the result into new column, i get an error `"'Series' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0'`. The line producing the error is as follows:

```
# Loop trough rows of a dataframe and write the result into new column
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: freq_value((row('a'), row('b'), row('c'))), axis = 1)
```

How exactly `row()` in `apply()` function works? Shouldn't it supply to my `freq_value()` function values from columns 'a', 'b', 'c'?

Comment: Try row['a'] instead row('a') in the apply call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is not a function within your `lambda`, so parentheses are not appropriate, Instead, you should use the `__getitem__` method or `loc` accessor to access values. The syntactic sugar for the former is `[]`:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: freq_value((row['a'], row['b'], row['c'])), axis=1)
```

Using the `loc` alternative:

```
def freq_value_calc(row):
    return freq_value((row.loc['a'], row.loc['b'], row.loc['c']))
```

To understand exactly *why* this is the case, it helps to rewrite your `lambda` as a named function:

```
def freq_value_calc(row):
    print(type(row))  # useful for debugging
    return freq_value((row['a'], row['b'], row['c']))

df['result'] = df.apply(freq_value_calc, axis=1)
```

Running this, you'll find that `row` is of type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`, i.e. a series indexed by column labels if you use `axis=1`. To access the value in a series for a given label, you can either use `__getitem__` / `[]` syntax or `loc`.

Answer (score 2):

@jpp's answer addresses how to apply your custom function, but you can also get the desired result using `df.mode`, with `axis=1`. This will avoid the use of `apply`, and will still give you a column of the most common value for each row.

```
df['result'] = df.mode(1)

>>> df
   a  b  c  result
0  1  1  1       1
1  2  1  2       2
2  1  2  2       2
3  2  1  1       1
4  1  1  2       1
5  2  1  2       2
6  1  2  2       2
7  1  2  1       1
```

Comment: Good point, also worth noting that `mode` has improved, it's now [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039106/9209546) versus all the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['CommonValue'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0], axis = 1)
```